# Whether the sequence $\{x_n-y_n\}$ converge or not.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given, $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are two real valued sequences such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (x_{n}^{3}-y_{n}^{3})=0 $

Then is it always true that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (x_n-y_n) =0 $ ?

I tried by splitting $ (x_{n}^{3}-y_{n}^{3}) $, but that didn't help as $\lim_{n\to \infty} (x_{n}^{2}+x_{n}y_{n}+y_{n}^{2}) $ can be $0$ or non zero or doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $x_n^3 -y_n^3 \to 0 $ implies $ x_n - y_n \to 0$ for real-valued sequences. This follows from the following estimate:

> For all $x, y \in \Bbb R$ is $|x-y| \le \sqrt[3]{4|x^3 - y^3|}$.

(In other words: the function $x \mapsto x^{1/3}$ is “[Hölder continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition)” with exponent $1/3$.)

Due to the symmetry, it suffices to prove the inequality for the case $x \ge y$:
$$
\begin{align}
 4(x^3-y^3) &= 4(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2) \\
&= (x-y)\left( (x-y)^2 + 3(x+y)^2\right) \\
&\ge (x-y)^3 \, .
\end{align}
$$

An alternative proof (which generalizes to other odd exponents) would be to compute the maximum of the function
$$
 f(u) = \frac{(u-1)^3}{u^3-1} = \frac{(u-1)^2}{u^2+u+1}
$$
which turns out to be $f(-1) = 4$.

Comment: $|x-y| \le \sqrt[3]{4|x^3 - y^3|}$, nice iequality!

Comment: Thank you, for nice explanation.

Comment: Autually, $x-y< (x^{1/p}-y^{1/p})^{p}$ for $0<p<1$ and $0<y<x$. Take $p=\frac{1}{2m+1}$.

Comment: @Riemann: Yes, but I wanted an inequality that holds for *all* $x, y$ (same sign or different sign), so that the conclusion $x_n^3 -y_n^3 \to 0 \implies x_n - y_n \to 0$ follows directly, without the need to consider separated cases.

Answer (score 9):

Suppose that $\lim_n(x_n-y_n)\ne 0$; then there are subsequences $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\langle y_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and an $\epsilon>0$ such that $|x_{n_k}-y_{n_k}|\ge\epsilon$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$. Infinitely many of the differences $x_{n_k}-y_{n_k}$ must have the same sign, so without loss of generality we may assume that $x_{n_k}-y_{n_k}\ge\epsilon$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$. Then $x_{n_k}\ge y_{n_k}+\epsilon$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$, and hence

$$\begin{align*}
x_{n_k}^3-y_{n_k}^3&\ge(y_{n_k}+\epsilon)^3-y_{n_k}^3\\
&=\epsilon\left(3y_{n_k}^2+3\epsilon y_{n_k}+\epsilon^2\right)\\
&=\epsilon\left(3\left(y_{n_k}+\frac{\epsilon}2\right)^2+\frac{\epsilon^2}4\right)\\
&\ge\frac{\epsilon^3}4
\end{align*}$$

for all $k\in\Bbb N$, contradicting the hypothesis that $\lim_n(x_n^3-y_n^3)=0$.

Comment: Thank you , for the nice explanation.

Comment: @Alearner: You're welcome.